# New R user having problems installing and running plotly package

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

A few months ago I created a shiny app using plotly. My laptop at the time crashed, and I have had to download R and RStudio on a new computer. I am having issues running the plotly library on the new computer, which isn't allowing the shiny app to run at all.

```
library(plotly)
```

> ```
> Loading required package: ggplot2
> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
>   there is no package called ‘colorspace’
> Error: package ‘ggplot2’ could not be loaded
> ```

I have searched other topics related to `ggplot2` errors like this, and none of the help from them has worked.

Comment: Did you try to install the `colorspace` package?

Comment: `install.packages('colorspace')`

Comment: Finally figured out how to use the formatting in comments... but anyways, I installed colorspace, and now `>library(plotly)` returns:  `Loading required package: ggplot2  

Attaching package: ‘plotly’

The following object is masked from ‘package:ggplot2’:

    last_plot

The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:

    layout`

Comment: Have you tried generating a plot after receiving this warning? You could also restart your R session, and run `library(plotly)` prior to anything else, and see if you still get the same warning.

Answer (score 0):

Installing colorspace and restarting R seemed to have fixed *this* problem, but now my formerly working shiny app is glitchy. That seems like a topic for a different question though.